# Mass search-and-replace of includes

Tags: c++, regex, replace, include

I have a lots of files that have includes in the following way:

```
#include <log4cxx/*whatever header file*>
```

I need to basically search and replace them, to change them to :

```
#include "log4cxx-0.10.0/src/main/include/log4cxx/*whatever header file*>
```

I've tried doing so without changing the `<>` to `""`  and it got messed up in the build.

I'm using eclipse as an IDE.

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: And the question is?  Do you want a way to do this with the IDE or do you want to build a program to do this for you?

Comment: The problem I have is changing the surrounding `<>` with `""`.

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to do it with eclipse, but I hoped someone would know how to do it

Comment: And adding `log4cxx-0.10.0/src/main/include` as an include path is not an option?

Comment: It's a good idea, but it's a no, since the normal include path already has a `log4cxx` folder, which is why it's conflicting. I need the `""` so that it would take my header files, and not the ones in `/usr/include/log4cxx`, which is what it's effectively trying to do

Comment: This is a job for [sed](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/sed.html).

Comment: I've already tried changing to everything with `<>`, which didn't work.

Comment: I don't know how to create a regex that would keep what's between the `<>` and place it between `""`

Comment: If Eclipse doesn't have regex search-and-replace, `sed` and `awk` spring to mind. Or, if you're using gcc, the `-I` (capital `i`) option will search that directory before the system includes.

Comment: It is easy as `(?m)^([ \t]*#include[ \t]+)<(log4cxx)(/[^>]*>)` > `$1"$2-0.10.0/src/main/include/log4cxx$3`. See https://regex101.com/r/kM2kA5/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I understand the regular expression, I changed it a bit, but how can I use it with sed? sed outputs: `sed: -e expression $1, char 50: unknown option to 's'`, when char 50 is the `$` in `$1`. I used sed like: `sed 's/*the expression*/*the substitution*/g'`

Comment: In sed, you will have to use `sed -E 's/^([[:blank:]]*#include[[:blank:]]+)<(log4cxx)(\/[^>]*>)/\1"\2-0.10.0\/src\/main\/include\/log4cxx\3/g'`.

Comment: output: `sed -e expression #1, char 103: Invalid character class name`, when char 103 is the `g` in the `log4cxx` before the `\3`

Comment: It works well, see https://ideone.com/nqDSMV. Are you using GNU sed?

Comment: I don't really know. What I do know tho, I've made a simpler approach. I've done the substitution of the first part, without the `>` in the end, and used a regex to replace the `>` with `"`, and it worked. But again, thanks so much Wiktor for your help, I really appreciate it! Spasiba Bolshoye!

Comment: Not at all, shall I post my solution?

Comment: You should prefer to not have directory paths in the source code.  Let the compiler search for the file and give the include path to the compiler.  This means that you don't have to modify the source files when the include files change directories (or the project / sandbox location is changed).

Answer (score 0):

If you open the files with emacs (text editor) you can use the command replace-regex and replace all of those `includes` by using the regular expression `#include <.(asterisk)>`. `.(asterisk)` means any group of zero or more characters.

substitute an asterisk for (asterisk)

Answer (score 0):

I would use notepad++ and do a "search and replace in files" with the extensions *.h;*.c and *.cpp etc.
As others have writen you would search for:

```
  #include <(log4cxx)/(.*)>
```

Replace with :

```
  #include "\1-0.10.0/src/main/include/\1/\2"
```